# Jquery и ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Доброго времени суток
есть библиотека [jquery](http://rouks.myjino.ru/pub/js/jquery.js)

а также вот такой код в скрипте

```
$('.join').click(function(){
    if (status==0){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $(".pop").height();
    var popupWidth = $(".pop").width();
    $(".back").css({"opacity": "0","height": windowHeight});
    $(".back").fadeIn("slow");
        $('.pop').fadeIn('slow');
        $('.pop').css({
            'bottom': -170,
            'left': 0
            });
            status=1;
        }
             
    });

    $('.back').click(function(){
        if (status==1) {
            $(".back").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".pop").fadeOut("slow");
            status=0;
            }
        });
    $('.close_button').click(function(){
        if (status==1){
            $(".back").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".pop").fadeOut("slow");
            status=0;
        }
        });
```

ну и html

```
<div class="top_navi join">Вход</div>
<div class="pop">
                        <input class="l_p" name="search" value="Логин" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Логин';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Логин') this.value='';" type="text">
                        <input class="l_p" name="search" value="Пароль" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Пароль';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Пароль') this.value='';" type="text">
                        <a href="javascript: alert('Страница в процессе разработки!');">Забыли пароль</a><br>
                        <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="first">
                        <label for="remember">Запомнить меня</label>
                        <button>Войти</button>
                        <span class="close_button">Закрыть</span>
                    </div>
    <div class="back"></div>
```

везде работает кроме ие8, окошко появляется но не закрывается, [пруф](http://rouks.myjino.ru/)

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: У вас используется на сайте синтаксис Masked Input, но при этом соответствующая библиотека не подключена.  
Это вызывает ошибку выполнения скрипта.  
Подключите библиотеку (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) сразу после подключения jQuery.

Comment: это не помогло, но спасибо за ответ